# fetch products if image is found in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress

i want to show image only products in woocommerce.

My fetch query is given below

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'stock' => 1, 'posts_per_page' => 9, 'orderby' =>'date','orderby' => 'rand' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

how can i get the image products only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this ?

```
<?php 
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'stock' => 1, 'posts_per_page' => 9, 'orderby' =>'date','orderby' => 'rand' );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog');
    endwhile;
?>
```

**UPDATED**

```
$args = array( 
                'post_type' => 'product', 
                'stock' => 1, 
                'posts_per_page' => 9, 
                'orderby' =>'date',
                'orderby' => 'rand', 
                'meta_query'=>array(
                    array(
                        'key'=>'_thumbnail_id', 
                        'compare' => 'EXISTS'
                    )
                )
            );
```

Change arg to get product if it has feature image.

Comment: no @Rohil_PHPBeginner i want to get products. Some products are not have product image. so i need to list image available products only. guide me

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner is correct. To query for products with a featured image you must run a meta query on the `_thumbnail_id` key. Though, Rohil, do you need to set the `'compare'=>'exists'` since you aren't searching for a specific value?