# Fetch products if image is found in woocommerce and filter the products

Tags: image, if-statement, woocommerce, fetch, product

I have a big problem, I used this code in my website - [fetch products if image is found in woocommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29936457/fetch-products-if-image-is-found-in-woocommerce/29936807#29936807?newreg=0e9f902fed0e4daca76376f34f898eb9)

```
<?php 
   $args = array( 
                'post_type' => 'product', 
                'stock' => 1, 
                'posts_per_page' => 9, 
                'orderby' =>'date',
                'orderby' => 'rand', 
                'meta_query'=>array(
                    array(
                        'key'=>'_thumbnail_id', 
                        'compare' => 'EXISTS'
                    )
                )
            );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog');
    endwhile;
?>
```

But I can't filter the products, do I have to put some variable in orderby? 
I can't put this in order

Comment: You are using `'orderby' => 'rand',` so the order will always be random. How do you want to order the items? What do you mean by filter?

Comment: I have on my website one input with anyone choise the order, like by price, date. I need put this on orderby.